# Xcode reuse detail view for multiple table views

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have multiple table views that display different items. The detail view for each cell though should have the same layout. I want to use the same detail view for all the cells of each table without having to implement a different detail view class for each table since it'll pretty much be the same code. How do I do this?

The following method is in one of the table views. This displays the detail view when a cell is selected:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath");
    AppDelegate *delegate =
        (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    Detail *detail=
        [[Detail alloc] initWithIndexPath:indexPath];

    [delegate.navController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

    [tv deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

The following is the viewDidLoad method in the Detail view class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *delegate =
    (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    PokemonInfo *thisPokemon = [delegate.allArray objectAtIndex:index.row];
    self.title = thisPokemon.name;

    nameView.text = thisPokemon.name;
    typeView.text = thisPokemon.type;
    attackView.text = thisPokemon.attack;
    attackView.editable = NO;
}
```

Comment: Justin,

You can have several ways to do so:
  - create a method which either initiate your detail view controller again & again. Pass the PokemonInfo object while initialization.
  - or alloc it once only & just use an instance method with your value object.

basically the things which you are performing in didLoad will put the load while the controller is being created.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I had a method that initiated the cell with the indexPath. I just changed the method so that it also accepts a key from the caller to identify which table it is so that it can display the appropriate array in the viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

Create the view and lay it out in a nib. Give each element a unique tag in the view. When you need a view instantiate using the nib (UINib), then access each element when you want to populate it by asking using "viewWithTag". Assuming you are recycling cells, the you always set any arbitrary view's elements with proper data.

That said above, the more traditional approach is to instantiate a cell in a nib, then do the same - each element you want to access has a unique tag.